# How to make score to be saved even if I reboot iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift

I made an app Single Application. I put a button called `CountUpButton`, a label called `CountLabel`, and another button `ResetButton`. The function of `CountUpButton` is when button is pressed, the `CountLabel` has to change `+ 1` and when `ResetButton` is pressed, `CountLabel` has to turn to `0`. But the problem is that whenever I reboot my iPhone or App, `CountLabel` turns back to 0. It's supposed `CountLabel` to be saved, so it have to change only when `ResetButton` is pressed.

The code of This function is:

```
var CountNumber = 0

@IBAction func ResetButton(sender: UIButton) {
    CountNumber = 0
    CountLabel.text = "0"
}

@IBOutlet var CountLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func CountUpButton(sender: UIButton) {
    CountNumber += 1
    CountLabel.text = "\(CountNumber)"
}
```

and code that I used for "CountLabel" to be saved is:

```
func saveCounted(){
    let defeaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defeaults.setInteger(CountNumber, forKey: "CountLabel")
}
```

Comment: Where do you *read* the value from the saved user defaults?

Comment: Ya I noticed it, I tried to fix this but I don't know how, I'm talking for forKey: "CountLabel"

Comment: In your viewDidLoad, put `CountNumber = NSUserDefaults.standardDefaults().IntegerForKey("CountLabel")` to initialize it with the value stored in the defaults.

Comment: In addition to what Martin asked, do you actually call the `saveCounted` function?

Comment: Ya I Did.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
saveCounted()
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    var counter: Int {
        return NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("counter")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        counterLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func countUp(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSUserDefaults().setInteger(counter+1, forKey: "counter")
        counterLabel.text = "\(counter)"

    }
    @IBAction func resetCounter(sender: AnyObject) {
         NSUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("counter")
        counterLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working bro, with this code is adding all counted numbesr so when app is loaded it shows all counted numbers added, ex: first time I counted 10, second time 20 and third time 20 and if I load app it shows 50.
It's supposed to show last counted number.

Comment: try to add a reset button, You will see what happens

Comment: I will add a reset button for you

Comment: Bro Thanks I will rate this Answer now, I made a little change in code so now it works, Thanks (Y)